# How to construct an xpath returning all of a set of elements

Tags: xpath

Considering theses xpath expressions :

```
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/span
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[3]/div[1]/h2/span
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[5]/div[1]/h2/span
```

For your info the div inside search result's class is article searchResult and the one inside article searchResult is header.

I am not sure how to construct an xpath matching all three of the above elements. Is there a tool or a how to guide for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use position function

```
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[position()=1 or position()=3 or position()=5]/div[1]/h2/span
```

Comment: Sorry I was not precise enough but in my situation matching elements are not always 3  but could be any number.

Comment: just remove index at all, if you want all

Answer (score 1):

If, by *'all'*, you mean *all* `div` in even position index, then you can use `mod` operator to check :

```
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[position() mod 2 = 1]/div[1]/h2/span
```

but if *'all'* literally means *all*, then you don't need index to return all matched elements :

```
//*[@id="searchResults"]/div/div[1]/h2/span
```